# PHP: Dynamically retrieving global variables

Tags: php

I am attempting to write a simple wrapper class to get the value of a global variable. I was thinking to use it like this:

```
print_r($class->session()->getAll());
print_r($class->cookie()->getAll());
```

Here's what I have:

```
class GlobalVars() {

  private $current;

  public function session() {
    $this->current = 'SESSION';
    return $this;
  }

  public function cookie() {
    $this->current = 'COOKIE';
    return $this;
  }

  public function getAll() {
    return $_{$this->current}; // Obviously wrong
  }

  public function get($key) {
    if (!isset($_{$this->current}[$key])) { // Obviously wrong
      return false;
    }

    return $_{$this->current}[$key]; // Obviously wrong
  }

  public function set($arr) {
    if (is_array($arr)) {
      foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        $_{$this->current}[$k] = $v;
      }
    }
  }

}

$class = new GlobalVars();

print_r($class->session()->getAll());
```

With this example, I get a `Notice: Undefined variable: _` message. What do I need to modify to get this to work?

Comment: Now, why would you do something like this?

Comment: You *can* do it with a functionality called "variable variables" but it's a terrible idea so I'll leave it to you to look it up.  Don't do abstraction for abstraction's sake. Have each of your public functions look up what you want from the proper variables.

Comment: what is that $_ thing?

Comment: A typical example of lack of knowledge of good architectural design, leading to perfect overengineering.

Comment: This is a totally valid questions guys I do not know why you want to close it. Sure it may be overengieneering but the question was "what to do to make this work" and not "is this great code"?

Comment: imo. If you decide to continue with this. Which is a terrible idea as you have lots of uncontrolled levels of global state in one place currently. You need to be able to specify which source you want retrieve the variable from in the `get` function. i.e. `public function get($key, $source) {...`.  Otherwise , you need to be able to specify the hierarchy of what order to search for the `$key` you provide. Also, you need to specify return the first found or all in the list of places to look. Please think very carefully about this. There are 'config' classes available that you can look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion this is just a simple syntactical error you have made. What you did:

```
  public function getAll() {
    return $_{$this->current}; // Obviously wrong
  }
```

But the correct way to emulate a variable from string is:

```
  public function getAll() {
    return ${"_".$this->current};
  }
```

I have tested it. Similar behaviour for the other variables. More information on variable variables in the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 1):

It's not gonna work like this. You need [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
$var = "_{$this->current}";
var_dump($$var['rnd']);
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/74f9e3649e80b8f2bab8704756dc783649d6b0c8)

---

It's very bad way to use varVars, because it's not readable and usually IDE does not know what are you using and it's easy to get buggy code.

Comment: Please, don't give him more ideas.